# CloudKit and iCloud account

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

I've been reading documentation and watching a few videos on this subject, and in all of them they mention the fact that users need to be authenticated with an iCloud account. My question is: if users don't have an iCloud account they won't be able to update the public database? And to put it in a little more context; can the apple account (the one the user needs to download stuff from the apple store) wouldn't be enough to update the public database and gain access to the private database?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if users don't have an iCloud account they won't be able to update the public database?

From Apple's [Designing for CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/DesigningforCloudKit/DesigningforCloudKit.html) doc:

> Saving records to the public database and accessing the private database in any way requires the presence of an active iCloud account on the device.

So you're right.

---

> can the apple account (the one the user needs to download stuff from the apple store) wouldn't be enough to update the public database and gain access to the private database?

This is a slightly unclear question -  cases where an Apple ID is set up to download from the App Store and *isn't* set up for iCloud are very rare. I would assume that nearly all devices that can download your app likely have an iCloud account attached to them.

Comment: If that's the case, then CloudKit won't affect affinity like I thought it would; I'll ask around the iPhone users I know to see if it's the case. In the meantime, this info has been really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: The key is "nearly". In most cases this will be true, but not all.

Comment: Can we edit records using public database? I mean using public database user A can access records of user B. But can user A able to edit records of user B?

Comment: I believe so, @Nikunj.

Comment: @Undo ok thanks, I had some doubts cause of description provided in framework. As in this question, I have posted it in separate thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25600556/cloudkit-can-we-modify-data-of-public-database

Comment: Whats the flow we should follow if they don't have an account?

Comment: @MobileBloke That's the big question. If iCloudKit is the main DB, people without iCloud Drive or even with iCloud, but turned off (it's small not cheap and fills fast by default), will not be able to use the App at all... I usually stick to Apple native as much as I can, but it sound like it's safer to use an external cloud DB.