# Cloudkit Can we modify data of public database

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud, ios8, cloudkit

I have just gone through the cloud kit doc as in this link [cloudkit](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/DesigningforCloudKit/DesigningforCloudKit.html) but not getting clear about to modify database records for public database. As per this description in cloudkit framework.

[image]

**Using Public Database**, as specified in image by default data are world readable, owner writable. That means only owner can modify his data other user can only read?
Suppose, using public database, user A can access records of user B, But can user A modify records of user B in same application.

Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In the CloudKit dashboard you are able to change the access rights. So it would be possible to make  records writable by others. You do have to be careful with this. When your app runs on a jailbroken device, then it's possible to execute methods with arbitrary arguments. This is a high security risk.

Comment: thanks for reply, That means we are only able to change access over dashboard, We can't do same with programmatically, correct?

Comment: If you want programmatic access rights, then maybe you could use zone's But then you do have to be careful with what to put in what zones since it is not possible to execute a query to fetch data from multiple zone's. Or just add your own access control by adding extra fields to your records and filter those. Then again there is a security risk on jailbroken devices because the security is only enforced on your phone and not in the iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

if you set your security setting within the record types on the dashboard, you can have all your public records set to be writeable by anyone without messing with the security roles.

```
Set Authenticated to Write
Set Creator to create.
```

[image]

p.s. you cannot 'world' read from the simulator, you need to be logged in on that. On the device though, you don't need to be logged in to read the public database :-) which is nice.

Comment: hi nik, do you know if there is another way to write the public database as an administrator, to seed and maintain data, without requiring a icloud login? full question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36808601/seed-and-maintain-cloudkit-public-database-still-requires-icloud-login

Comment: not that i'm aware of. admins needs to be linked with the cloud kit production environment which is linked to the devs dev account.